# NGINX keeps redirecting www.example.com/some-path to example.com/ -- How to stop?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have no experience with NGINX, but about 12 years with Apache. No clue how I got stuck with this server running NGINX, but I'm trying to make the best of it.

Anyway, no matter what I do, going to www.example.com/some-path always takes me to example.com (no path), but going to example.com/some-path works fine. Any idea how to fix this? Client is going to kill me if I don't figure this out soon!

Thanks!

Edit:
Here is NGINX config

```
    #user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on; include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Edit Again:
**conf.d**

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/webmail.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/forwarding/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/wildcards/*.conf;
```

**server.conf**

```
    #ATTENTION!
    #
    #DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
    #SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

    include "/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/*.conf";

    server {
            listen [my ip, hidden for security]:80;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://[my ip, hidden for security]:7080;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }

    server {
            listen [my ip, hidden for security]:443 ssl;

            ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWLTI39G;
            ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWLTI39G;
            ssl_session_timeout         5m;

            ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
            ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://[my ip, hidden for security]:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;

server {
        listen [my ip, hidden for security]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWLTI39G;
        ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/certWLTI39G;
        ssl_session_timeout         5m;

        ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://[my ip, hidden for security]:7081;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Another edit:
**vhosts/housedoctors.com.conf**

```
server {
        listen [my ip, hidden for security]:80;

        server_name housedoctors.com;
        server_name www.housedoctors.com;
        server_name ipv4.housedoctors.com;

        client_max_body_size 128m;

        root "/var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/httpdocs";
        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/housedoctors.com/logs/proxy_access_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/housedoctors.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://[my ip, hidden for security]:7080;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;
        }

        location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
alias /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/httpdocs/;
                add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
                internal;
        }
```

Comment: Show your nginx configuration, at least.

Comment: OK...but where are the `server` blocks? Check the `include` directories for the rest of your configuration.

Comment: I'm using Plesk -- could that dictate where they go?

Comment: Post content of files included ... `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: There you go, Xavier.

Comment: I don't see any redirects there. Look for something Plesk has added in one of its include directories.

Comment: Oh my god, disable SSLv2 **ASAP** !!

Comment: Just added the final conf file that was site specific. Also, what's SSLv2!?!?!

Comment: @AllenGingrich A protocol intended to secure communications and  suffering major security flaws. Deprecated since 1996. Use SSLv3 (with strong ciphers), TLS1, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 only.

Comment: Good call, thanks. Any clue on the redirect? This is driving me mad -- 6 hours in on this issue.

Comment: If there are no other `server` blocks on the nginx config, then it must be the proxied application that is doing the redirects.

Comment: How is your application managing the 3 different Host headers ?

Answer (score -1):

Search for a line with the word `rewrite` in it and comment it out with a `#`.
If you have commented them all out, and you are still being redirected, check if the redirect might be cached in your browser.

### Warning: This method can break things

Comment: It's certainly not the good way to investigate on a production issue. There is something called log.

Comment: There was no clue that this was a production system.

Comment: The OP mentions this is for a client so not a hard guess. Also I can rephrase if you prefer : it's certainly not the good way to investigate **any** issue, in **any** environment. Kinda remind me these funny folks using javascript alert boxes to debug their code : just no.

Comment: He also mentioned he wants it fast and he is unexperienced with nginx. This is fast and simple.

Comment: So you have someone unexperienced that enters in panic mode. You advise him to worsen the problem by removing random parts of the configuration he's clueless on ? This will surely delight the client. You have ways to investigate without killing the things that work.

Comment: Like I said. I didn't assume it was a live application. I will amend my post with a warning.